# Enunciate doc generation issue with Java Restful webservices

Tags: enunciate

Am trying to generate the REST doc using the enunciate plugin for my JAVA restful webservice project. whenever I run the POM.xml using the maven build. am getting the below warning and doc is not at all generating..

[WARNING] [docs] Splash package com.layer.rest.service.interfaces not found.  No splash documentation included.

any clue pls ?

Comment: Can you put a bit of code in your question? like the pom.xml and web.xml (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Enunciate tries to use the JavaDoc in package-info.java in the package you define in enunciate.xml, like this:

```
<enunciate label="Foo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modules>
    <docs title="My Foo API"
        splashPackage="org.foo"  />
```

Based on this configuration, enunciate will look for `org.foo.package-info.java`. If it cannot be found, it shows the warning you got.

For more details, refer to the `docs` module documentation here: https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Module-Docs